# Align two minipages horizontal

Tags: minipage, frame

I want to align two minipages inside a frame horizontaly

```
\begin{frame}[t]{3.1 WaveNet}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Aufbau:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Dilated Convolution
    \item Residual Blöcke
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Gated Aktivation 
    \item Softmax-Verteilung
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figs/Dilation.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
 
\end{frame}
```

This is the code that gives me this result:
[image]
And now I want to algin the two list. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Either move `\textbf{Aufbau:}` outside of the first `minipage`  or use `[b]` instead of `[t]` for both `minipage` environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either move `\textbf{Aufbau:}` outside of the first `minipage` or use `[b]` instead of `[t]` for both `minipage` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{3.1 WaveNet}
\textbf{Aufbau:}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Dilated Convolution
    \item Residual Blöcke
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Gated Aktivation 
    \item Softmax-Verteilung
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]{3.1 WaveNet}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Aufbau:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Dilated Convolution
    \item Residual Blöcke
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Gated Aktivation 
    \item Softmax-Verteilung
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```